# adding a video / gallery icon next to post title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, title, html

I want to add a video icon / gallery icon next to title, which post contain video / photo gallery. Im on latest wordpress and making my own custom theme. Currently im using

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

for title. I was worked on another theme (not mine) before which have video icon on titles. The code i found in functions.php

```
<?php
 function title_embed($title,$conts)
        {
                $pattern ="/<object> ?.* <\/object>/isx";
                $return =preg_match($pattern, $conts,$result);
                if($result)
                {
                    $return = $title.'<span class="video-icon"></span>';
                    return $return;
                }    
                else{return $title;}        
}
```

which makes a span class on titles on posts contains `<object>` and `</object>`. The title code was

```
 <a href="<?php echo $arraybox['link'][0];?>" title="<?php echo $arraybox['alt'][0];?>"><h2><?php echo $arraybox['title'][0];?></h2></a>
```

I've tried pasting the above code to my current theme's functions.php but nothing happened. I think the problem may be the way I'm calling title. I've googled for a resource and wasted my 6-7 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, your code looks for `<object> </object>` tags in the content and
if found it appends the span whose class is video-icon to the title. This span will probably be styled as a video icon in css.

Have you tried calling your function with `$conts= the_content()`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I know the script is looking for object text in the post. But dont know how to call to my current title which is '<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>'
 can you please explain, I'm not a php guy..

Comment: @Kanu Pasting code into functions.php is not going to make it create your video icon. Functions.php in wordpress is just a store of good to use functions. Basically you are telling wordpress that you may use the title_embed() function in your theme files. Are you actually calling this function eg in your index.php file or home.php. For example if i want the icons to appear on the home page i edit home.php file and instead of "the_title()" i use title_embed(get_the_title(),get_the_content()) or something. In all the code you are showing us you never actually call the title_embed() function.

Comment: thank you, I know my problem is calling the title, that's what i'm asking. As i said above I'm not good in PHP, what about the first code (old theme code) I did not seen any title_embed() function on old them, they just calling ' <a href="<?php echo $arraybox['link'][0];?>" title="<?php echo $arraybox['alt'][0];?>"><h2><?php echo $arraybox['title'][0];?></h2></a>' . Or some other function overriding this title calling in my new theme. Can you please give me a explained code. I just want to add an icon next to title whic post contains video or image gallery. Is there any other option for that?

Comment: somebody please give some basic php code for this? I dont know the rules here.. so please someone...

Comment: @kanu sorry I have been dealing with a nasty Exam for the last 24hrs. To give you more specific instructions post a link to download the theme you are working on and a link to the theme whose functionality you want to emulate.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and time, currently I'm at my home. I'll post the link once I reached office tomorrow(Indian time after 10am). Should I post the link here (is it safe?) or any option to send you directly? whatever please check this post tomorrow. Once again a big thanks for your time

Comment: could i send links directly to you? I'm working with a reputed company. If they found I'm asking help for their site, that's may not good for me (Don't hate me). I know the power of stackoverflaw. Just search "video icon next to title" this page comes first in Google. If no other options, I'll post the links here tomorrow. BTW this page's content appearing some another sites.eg (http://phpmagister.com/adding-a-video-gallery-icon-next-to-post-title-in-wordpress-18648/)

Comment: thanks, I'll send it tomorrow, Please ignore the above comment

Comment: mail sent, Please check your spam box also because it contain links and images

Comment: Seems like you need to replace the_title() with echo title_embed(get_the_title(),get_the_content()). Check email. Am not comfortable using email bcoz its slow and I dont get a chance to learn from others

Comment: Dont know how to express my thanks Dr Deo, Works super. How can make this post answered and if possible giving you some reputation.

Comment: Click the tick next to the answer to accept it as the correct answer